# Is there a way to make the java timer fire a certain number of times, then stop?

Tags: java, timer

Ok, so I need a timer to fire X number of times, ie. 5 times, and I know how to make it all work, but I can't figure out this one problem. If there isn't just some invoked method, then maybe there's a different way to do something like that? but here's the code i'm working with;

```
int delay = 5000;
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    //some action here
  }
};

new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

(also, if theres anything wrong with this code, please tell me. Thanks!)

Comment: Couldn't you just make a global counter that increments every time the timer is fired?

Comment: yes maintain a counter and stop the timer at specific value of counter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Timer t;
int firecount = 0;    

int delay = 5000;
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {        
    // action code
    firecount++;

    if ( firecount == 5 )
      t.stop();
};

t = new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

Comment: holy crap this site responds amazingly fast. I asked, went to cut up a peach, and came back. awesome! But, yeah, I did think of something like a counter, but #1. Didn't know how #2. Thought that there'd be something simpler. anyway, thanks, man. That solves that.